# How to make multiple insert in Inertia Vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, multiple-columns, inertiajs

I think not much people using Inertia jetstream lately and i just got stuck in making multiple insert(record) in my program. i know the concept is making array data in your form to make request to controller and save the data but maybe i still nob in this so still figuring out so much thing and i am not the explaining type myself:

```
<template>
<div>
    <jet-button @click="createTimDetail">
        Create New
    </jet-button>

    <!-- Delete Account Confirmation Modal -->
    <jet-dialog-modal :show="creatingTimDetail" @close="closeModal">
        <template #title>
            Create TimDetail
        </template>

        <template #content>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Tim</label>
                <select
                class="form-control"
                @change="getAnggota(temp_section_id)"
                v-model="temp_section_id"
                >
                <option v-for="tim in tims" :value="tim.id">{{tim.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nama Anggota</th>
                        <th>Posisi</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(tims, index) in banyakAnggota">
                        {{setTimId(index, tims.id)}}
                        <td>
                            <select class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-3/4"
                                v-model="record[index].nip" >
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Anggota</option>
                                <option v-for="karyawan in karyawans" :key="karyawan.nip" :value="karyawan.nip">{{karyawan.nama}}</option>
                            </select>

                            <jet-input-error :message="form.errors.nip" class="mt-2" />                                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <jet-input type="text" class="mt-1 block w-3/4" placeholder="Posisi Anggota"
                                        ref="posisi"
                                        v-model="record[index].posisi"
                                        @keyup.enter="create" />

                            <jet-input-error :message="form.errors.posisi" class="mt-2" />                                
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>
 <!-- Footer for button-->
        <template #footer>
            <jet-secondary-button @click="closeModal">
                Cancel
            </jet-secondary-button>

            <jet-button class="ml-2" @click="create" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" :disabled="form.processing">
                Create
            </jet-button>
        </template>
    </jet-dialog-modal>
</div>
```

Can you guys help me. Maybe help with the concept :). i try to add much team member for a team but the array cant send the data

```
<script>
import JetButton from '@/Jetstream/Button.vue'
import JetDialogModal from '@/Jetstream/DialogModal.vue'
import JetInput from '@/Jetstream/Input.vue'
import JetInputError from '@/Jetstream/InputError.vue'
import JetSecondaryButton from '@/Jetstream/SecondaryButton.vue'
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'

export default {
components: {
    JetButton,
    JetDialogModal,
    JetInput,
    JetInputError,
    JetSecondaryButton,
},

props: {
    tims: Array,
    karyawans:Array
},

data() {
    return {
        creatingTimDetail: false,
        record:[],
        banyakAnggota:[],
        temp_section_id:0,

        form: this.$inertia.form({
            tim_id: '',
            nip: '',
            posisi: '',
        })
    }
},

mounted () {
},

methods: {
    setTimId(index, tim_id){
        this.record[index].tim_id = tim_id
    },
    createTimDetail() {
        this.fetchKaryawans();
        this.fetchTims();
        this.creatingTimDetail = true;

        setTimeout(() => this.$refs.posisi.focus(), 250)
    },

    fetchTims() {
        Inertia.reload({ only: ['tims'] })
    },

    fetchKaryawans() {
        Inertia.reload({ only: ['karyawans'] })
    },
    getAnggota(){
        Inertia.reload({ only: ['tims'] + this.temp_section_id}).post(
            response => {
                this.record = [];
                var data = response.data;
                for (let index = 0; index<=response.data.length; index++){
                    this.addRow();
                    if(data[index].tim_detail != null){
                        this.record[index].nip = data[index].tim_detail.nip;
                        this.record[index].posisi = data[index].tim_detail.posisi;
                    }
                }
                this.banyakAnggota = response.data;
            }
        )            
    },

    create() {
        this.form.post(route('timDetail.store'), {
            preserveScroll: true,
            preserveState: true,
            onSuccess: () => {
                this.closeModal();
                this.form.reset();
            },
        })
    },

    closeModal() {
        this.creatingTimDetail = false
        this.form.clearErrors()
        this.form.reset()
    },
    addRow(){
        this.record.push({
            tim_id:null,
            nip:null,
            posisi:null
            
        })
    }        
},
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is not clear what you want.
Put some code, behavior and expected.

Comment: or maybe you can just give me some example of multiple insert from one of your project please ;)))))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, i think what exactly i need in the code is how the multiple insert work so i can insert a team with 6/7 members at once

Comment: i think the prime problem is in the getAnggota